# Call non static method in javascript from code behind in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am having a non static method in aspx.cs file and want to call that method using javascript/jQuery.
I have seen many examples but none of them help i getting error like internal error 500 in javascript console.

here is the code

method in aspx.cs file

```
  public void methodname()
{
    // populating repeater 
    rp.DataSource = datatable;
    rp.DataBind();
}
```

and in aspx file

```
  function updateRepeater() {
        console.log("update called");
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "aspx/methodname",
            data: '{}',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            success: function (result) {
                console.log("Success");
            },
            error: function (msg) {
                console.log("Error");
            }
        });
    }
```

but its not working i have also tried web method but it work with only static methods so can't use that.

can anyone tell me how to do this or i m doing anything wrong.

the error i get in console is

```
  jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2
  POST http://localhost:1003/foldername1/foldername2/PageNAme.aspx/MethodName 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Comment: Does your code actually say `"aspx/methodname"`?

Comment: what do u mean? @ChrisG

Comment: its a pagename.aspx/mymethodname

Comment: I'm not an asp.net expert but I'm just wondering how the server gets from a request for "methodname" to calling `BiddingTeamCount()`

Comment: i edited the above question now just have a look @ChrisG

Comment: You cannot do what you're attempting to do. You can call a non-static method by marking it as a WebMethod, but then the method won't be a part of your page context, thus it won't have any access to your repeater. That's simply not how Web Forms works. If you need to retrieve the data, your best bet is to either perform a postback or better yet, abandon the Web Forms approach all together and just retrieve the data as JSON via calling a server side method, and use that to update the front end view.